# A way to get single contiguous text block for all text from Google cloud vision OCR?

Tags: google-apis-explorer

The problem is I want to use Google Cloud Vision to scan receipts. Receipts are always one block of contiguous text. The default response from the documentTextDetection API is sectioned into blocks, often splitting item name and price in variable ways. This is very useful but not for this case.

Is there is a way to tell the documentTextDetection api to return one single block? If not is there an example of stitching the vertices together to get to same result?

```
Sample Receipt Image input:

Beer                        £2.99
Coffee                      £6.99
Chocolate                   £0.99


Response:

{textAnnotations: [
{
  {description: '£2.99'},
  {description: '£6.99'},
  {description: '£0.99'}
},
{
  {description: 'Beer'},
  {description: 'Coffee'},
  {description: 'Chocolate'}
}
]

Desired response where item name matched to price:
{textAnnotations: [
{
  {description: 'Beer      £2.99'},
  {description: 'Coffee .  £6.99'},
  {description: 'Chocolate £0.99'}
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assemble the response by hand iterating over full_text_annotation, pages, blocks, sections, words. There is an attribute in words.symbol.property.detected_break that tells when there are breaks, in your case if the symbol is the last of the line the value would be equal to 3.